# Why this system table doesn't appear on dictionary table?

Tags: oracle, audit

How you can see I am the sys:

```
SQL> show user;
     USER is "SYS"
```

When I search the table in the dictionary the dictionary returns no rows:

```
select table_name from dictionary where table_name like '%AUDIT_UNIFIED_ENABLED_POLICIES%';

no rows selected
```

but if I issue the desc command I receive the structure of the table

```
desc AUDIT_UNIFIED_ENABLED_POLICIES
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(128)
 POLICY_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(128)
 ENABLED_OPT                                        VARCHAR2(7)
 ENABLED_OPTION                                     VARCHAR2(15)
 ENTITY_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(128)
 ENTITY_TYPE                                        VARCHAR2(7)
 SUCCESS                                            VARCHAR2(3)
 FAILURE                                            VARCHAR2(3)
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any proper explanation. It has always been like this. Maybe Oracle was lazy, forgot to update the `DICTIONARY` view and noone even bothered to report this. Maybe there is a real reason for this.

If you check the definiton of the view `DICTIONARY` (`DICT` is a synonym for that), you can see it is a union of 3 branches (simplified):

1. `ALL_*`, `DBA_*`, `USER_*` views
2. A specific list of other views
3. Some others views that have public synonyms created on them with a different name (like `DICTIONARY` and `DICT`)

The problem is with `2.` in my opinion. These newer views do not follow the regular naming schema and they should be included in this list.

I had the same experience with views related to Data Redaction.

Views such as `REDACTION_POLICIES` or `REDACTION_COLUMNS` are also not listed in `DICT`/`DICTIONARY`.